# vanilla js & typescript event referencing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to ask if there is any way to annotate the type of the `e` parameter in this code:

```
const onDrag = () => {
    // Input element
    const range = document.querySelector('input') as HTMLInputElement;

    // Paragrahp element
    const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#used-data') as HTMLElement;

  // THIS ONE HERE
    range.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        rangeValue.textContent = `${e} GB`;
    });
};

onDrag();
```

Btw, the `range` variable is a range input element. The inferred annotation of `e` is an `event` and it seems that I cant access the value using `e.target.value`. Aside from assigning the type of `e` as `any` or by using `function() this.value`, is there another way to do this?

Comment: according to the official typescript typings, the event-object for a change-event is typed as `Event`. [here it's defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L11142) and here [the line in the mapping table](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L8832)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has a pretty good and straight forward online documentation which could be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html).

In general, types are annotates by passing a colon and the variable type afterwards. The events "change" and "input" are both typed as `InputEvent`. Your code will look like the following:

```ts
    range.addEventListener('change', (e: InputEvent) => {
        rangeValue.textContent = `${e.data} GB`;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your feed back but `InputEvent` doesn't seem to work. It says

`Argument of type '(e: InputEvent) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLInputElement, ev: Event) => any'.`

Comment: @JhunsenSamonte looks like you have TS strict mode enabled which [checks function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) more strictly. That's a good thing. Changing `e: InputEvent` to `e: Event` should fix the error.

Comment: Hi @KrisztiánBalla. Yes, I did that already but `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` doesn't work with just `Event`. I really wonder why tho -_-

Comment: you need to assert `target` first in any case - it is defined to have a type `EventTarget | null`

Comment: Hi @OlegValter. Still can't access it. This is my sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-meninsky-tzk9k?file=/src/index.ts).

Comment: @JhunsenSamonte [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Maybe we should use something like codepen so that we can access the DOM? Am I correct @OlegValter?

Comment: runtime is not important when we talk about types... The standard definitions library is responsible for typing the listeners...

Comment: Sorry for being noob. [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgJwIYHMYF4YAoCmAuAUQDccxYAfGY0qAFSQRRygEoMA+GAbwFgAoGDBwA6KAyZRhRJABsArjgDc-AL5A)

Comment: `EventTarget` is not an `Event`, obviously if you make a union between two unrelated interfaces you will not be able to access any properties within

Comment: Is there a way to access HTMLElement properties in `(e: ??? ) => e.target.value`?

Comment: @JhunsenSamonte - a type assertion to `HTMLElement` of the `target` needs no be done (that's the simplest solution). Obviously, `e` is always either an `Event` or a subtype of it (like a `UIEvent`, or `InputEvent`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @OlegValter in the comments, this can be done by asserting the type of event's target:

```
range.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        e.target.textContent = `${e} GB`;
    }
});

// Or if you prefer to use guard clause:
range.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement)) return;

    e.target.textContent = `${e} GB`;
});
```

This needs to be done, as the `Event` interface defines `target` and `currentTarget` properties as `readonly currentTarget: EventTarget | null;`.